# How to get attributes of XML root element using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an XML file with the root element name wwwjob. This root element contains attributes, I need to access the value of the 'method' attribute to be able to update various database entries.

This is a little bit of a learning curve at the moment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <wwwjob id="32cca11IACH" method="Delete">
   some more xml stuff
 </wwwjob>
```

Ive tried:

```
<?php $xml = $vacancyXML->wwwjob['method']; ?>
```

This just gave me 'NULL'.

Ive also tried:

```
 <?php $xml = $vacancyXML->getName(); ?>
```

This just spits out the name 'wwwjob'.

I need to store the method (Delete/Update/Add) as a variable for use in later parts of the function.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When loadinG to simplexml, attributes of the root element became attributes of the simpleXml object. So, you can get it just

```
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <wwwjob id="32cca11IACH" method="Delete">
 </wwwjob>';
$vacancyXML = simplexml_load_string($str);

echo $vacancyXML['method']; // Delete
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/955596)

Comment: Marked as the anaswer purly because its closer to the syntax Im using in my function.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the attributes of the root element with [`SimpleXMLElement::attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php):

```
$www = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo $www->attributes()->method; // Delete
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/1bseu)